# How do you cd to a hidden system folder in Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: cmd, cd

If I try to change directory inside the Windows 10 command prompt to a hidden system folder, even if I run as administrator, I get an Access is Denied message.

Example:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\config\system
```

When I type in: `dir /a`
the folder is shown

I could take ownership of the folder, but I can't help but think there is a better way.

Comment: Do `cd /D` rather than `cd` in order to switch the drive also in case. Anyway, `dir /A "C:\Windows\system32\config\system"` should tell you that `system` is a file rather than a directory...

Comment: I would normally migrate this question to [SU], since it is about normal computer usage, not programming, and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, since it was caused by a typo and is unlikely to be useful to others in the future, I’ve just closed it.

Comment: I must have been blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Windows 10 machine, "system" is a file, not a directory. cd to c:\Windows\System32\config instead.